# return substring of a dynamic ping

Tags: shell, ping, for

When I run `ping example.com`, it prints the result of each exchange in the console. I'd like to filter each result so that, instead of showing all the information, it shows only a subset of it.

So, instead of:

```
PING example.com (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=1201 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=783 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=417 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34 (93.184.216.34): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=159 ms
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=886 ms
```

I want the result printed in the terminal to be:

```
1201ms
783ms
417ms
159ms
886ms
```

I'll accept `ping` specific answers, but I'd prefer a general answer that can accept any dynamic process and process each string it returns to some other string, because that would be more general. I'm especially interested in a shell solution to this, the same way `xargs` is a shell solution to the limitations of some programs to accept pipe redirection.

Comment: That output is neither machine readable nor human readable. Don't you maybe want one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion uses `sed`. I don't understand what you mean about your dynamic strings, other than you want to transform something to something else. Most filters will do that.

```
ping -c 3 1.1.1.1 | sed -En 's/.*=([0-9.]+) ([a-z]+)$/\1\2/p'
32.5ms
34.5ms
37.5ms
```

Comment: This answer works too. Though I liked the other one better as it was shorter.  thanks for your feedback

Comment: @honestSalami although I'm pleased to hear you've got an answer that works for you, the output from the other one doesn't match your stated requirement. If you didn't care about whitespace between the number and the "ms", you could have had several short answers

Comment: I see, you worked really hard to delete those whitespaces. I'll admit that I deleted the whitespace accidentally during the question posting. Since your answer matches the requirements of the question better, I should accept yours instead

Comment: That's messed up. But the guy badly needed some more votes. :-))

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you mean by "accept any dynamic process", but in your `ping` case you could pipe its output to `cut`

```
ping example.com | cut -d= -f4
12.6 ms
11.3 ms
19.4 ms
```

Comment: dynamic process is a term I made up for something I don't know the name of. Lets see, every successful packet, ping prints a message and a newline. What I want to do is capture each newline as its printed, and filter its contents. The other answers wait for the ping command do a certain number of packets, then filters all of the lines at once. Can you help me give a name to that? was I able to explain myself?

Comment: No, nothing waits for "all at once". With `|` pipe, lines are filtered as they come.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It was my mistake that I did not test the answer for myself. Thank you so much!